# Global tide data - is it out there?

Tags: data-request, geospatial, global, oceanographic

I'm looking for a tidal range GIS layer. Anything global that shows either mean tidal range, maximum tidal range, or maximum tidal height. I have been trawling the web for tide related GIS layers and they don't seem to be available. If any one knows of a source, please let me know!

Comment: http://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/find-tides-currents.html and https://tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/map/ may or may not be helpful. These are point tide measurements/predictions, not "shapefiles", but it may be a start.

Comment: @BarryCarter can you post your comment as an answer? (since this is highly vote and still unanswered, and it seems nothing better out there)

Comment: Done. I don't really think it's answer-worthy, but since you have a diamond by your name and I agree there are too many "unanswered-but-answered questions", I figured it'd be ok.

Comment: Well usually tide is only relevant to maritime users at the coast. So it will be quite difficult to get something 2D based on measurements. Some simulation data should be available by those who calculate tide tables. In principle you could look for measured absolute wave height, but my guess is, that you'll only get relative measurements, as that is what is relevant for ships.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=3d626ffd8ca1483ca37d32fd430b277d

This data is available as of 2020 and I think is what people are looking for! It was computed using the FES2014 model data obtained from AVISO. It is possible you need an ERSI account to access it.

Answer (score 2):

https://oceanservice.noaa.gov/facts/find-tides-currents.html and https://tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/map may or may not be helpful. These are point tide measurements/predictions, not "shapefiles", but it may be a start.

Comment: In principle you could use some form of interpolation on that data, and you would be done.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I was hoping someone out there had created a shapefile already, but I might have to go ahead and make one using interpolation as suggested - I will be sure to post here if/when I have that. Cheers for the help.

Comment: @Mike You might contact NOAA directly. They may have info they don't post or that's available but hard to find on their site.